# Windows 10 Universal application - embedding different native libraries depending on architecture

Tags: visual-studio, dll, windows-store-apps, native, win-universal-app

I created a blank Windows 10 Universal application with Visual Studio 2015 RC:

`File > New > Project ... > Windows Universal > Blank App (Windows Universal)`

I want to use existing native libraries provided by a third-party. Those libraries are built from a C codebase and only use whitelisted Windows Store APIs.

I copied `foo.dll` beside `App1.vcxproj` then added it to the project and modified link settings to use `foo.lib` (the import library corresponding to `foo.dll`) for the x86 architecture. I also right-clicked `foo.dll` and set the `Content` property to `Yes` which makes Visual Studio embed the `.dll` with the application.

So far so good, I can use / debug my app that makes use of the third-party library. Visual Studio somehow deploys `foo.dll` next to `App1.exe` inside the `AppX` folder. And `foo.lib` (the import library for `foo.dll`) manages to load `foo.dll` successfully when the application start (this is because `foo.dll` is deployed next to `App1.exe`).

---

Now, for that third-party library, I have one `.dll` file per architecture:

```
foo/bin/x86/foo.dll
foo/bin/x86/foo.lib

foo/bin/x64/foo.dll
foo/bin/x64/foo.lib

foo/bin/arm/foo.dll
foo/bin/arm/foo.lib
```

And here comes my question: while keeping a single Visual Studio project for my app, how can I convince Visual Studio to:

- deploy `foo/bin/x86/foo.dll` next to `App1.exe` when building for x86
- deploy `foo/bin/x64/foo.dll` next to `App1.exe` when building for x64
- deploy `foo/bin/arm/foo.dll` next to `App1.exe` when building for arm

What I tried so far is putting the different `foo.dll` files inside solution folders, e.g.

```
third-party/foo/x86/foo.dll
third-party/foo/x64/foo.dll
third-party/foo/arm/foo.dll
```

That could have worked since I can conditionally set the `Content` property to `Yes` for each `.dll` file. However, using solution folders makes Visual Studio deploy the `.dll` file in a sub-folder, e.g. `AppX\third-party\foo\x86\foo.dll` for the x86 architecture. Consequently when the application starts it doesn't find the shared library anymore. I wish there was a way to control deployment target location, I think that would solve my use case.

Hope my explanations are clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a pre-build command line — per configuration so you can copy the right DLL from different source folders to project folder before packaging.